# How to add json property and value to an empty collection in a jobject?

Tags: c#, json, jobjectformatter

I have a `Jobject` `Car`. 
The `Car` has a `null` collection 'wheels'.

How could I add property and values to the collection `wheels`?

**Code:**

```
{
  "Car": {
    "engine": 2,
    "wheels": []
  }
}
```

**What I expect:**

```
{
  "Car": {
    "engine": 2,
    "wheels": [
      {
        "frontWheel": 2,
        "rearWheel": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to add `frontwheel` and `rearwheel` to the `JObject`?

Comment: Is an array really the right data structure to use?

Comment: yes, "wheels" is a collection

Comment: Why don't you use the serializer? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: serialize and deserialize would effect performace. im looking at something like jobject.selectToken("car.wheels").add("frontWheel")

Answer (score 0):

To create your desired output using `Newtonsoft.Json`, you create an instance of `JArray` and populate it with instances of type `JObject`.

```
var result = new JObject(
    new JProperty("engine", 2),
    new JProperty("wheels", 
        new JArray
        {
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("frontWheel", 2),
                new JProperty("rearWheel", 2))
        }));
```

This will produce the following output:

```
{
  "engine": 2,
  "wheels": [
    {
      "frontWheel": 2,
      "rearWheel": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Alternatively you could use the serialization mechanism provided by `Newtonsoft.Json`